# How to call static block in knockout template file?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am Using Magento 2.1.

Want to show some custom shipping message for shipping method on checkout page, I have done it by editing directly to the knockout template file.

> Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html

but I want this setting on backend. So, is is possible to call a static block in knockout template file, if yes, how can I do it.

I want the contant in red box to come form static block.

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can create a module that will make your cms block message available to the KO template by adding to the checkout config.

In `Your/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml` we add a new config provider to the checkout config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="cms_block_config_provider" xsi:type="object">Your\Module\Model\ConfigProvider</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

In `Your/Module/Model/ConfigProvider.php` we have the code that fetches the cms block's html:

```
<?php

namespace Your\Module\Model;


use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface;

class ConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    /** @var LayoutInterface  */
    protected $_layout;

    public function __construct(LayoutInterface $layout)
    {
        $this->_layout = $layout;
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        $cmsBlockId = 1; // id of cms block to use

        return [
            'cms_block_message' => $this->_layout->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId($cmsBlockId)->toHtml()
        ];
    }
}
```

Now you should overwrite the shipping.html KO template in your theme where you can display the cms block like so:

```
<div data-bind="html: window.checkoutConfig.cms_block_message"></div>
```

Note: if you want to use html tags that contain double quotations (for example an html a tag) in the static block you should escape the double quotations with a backslash. For example:

```
Accept our <a target=\"_blank\" href=\"/privacy-policy\">privacy policy</a>
```

Comment: Can I do same to append CMS block into minicart content.html?

Comment: For the minicart you will need to make a plugin in for `getConfig` method of `\Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar`. This method returns an array that is then passed to javascript as the `window.checkout` object (this occurs in  `Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml`).

Comment: @AaronAllen,  it's working thank you for this post.

Comment: Can anyone say will this work for 2.3.3 as i don't see the cms static block content displayed? @Sarfaraj Sipai

Comment: Thank @AaronAllen, This have working on ver 2.3.3.

Comment: This does indeed work for CMS blocks, but do you have any idea how to do this for phtml templates?

Answer (score -6):

I think you cant call static block in .html file you have to add that static block code in phtml file

Try the below path

```
Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/templates/onepage.phtml
```

try to add the below code maintain by come css hacks

```
you have to change **static-block-id**


<div class ="static block" style="bottom: 127px; position: absolute;">
<?php   echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('static-block-id')->toHtml();   ?>
</div>
```

This is temporary solutions might be you will get some other good Answers