# Magento 2 Knockout XML->PHTML->JS->HTML

Tags: magento2, xml, phtml, knockoutjs, html

I want to display static block in html login popup during checkout, but there is a problem.

This is the **html** template which is called from **js**, this *js* is called from **phtml**, and this *phtml* template called from **xml**
 layout. 
( **xml -> phtml -> js -> html**)

So the question is how to send custom content block from the *phtml* or *xml* throught *js* to *html* template

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

This file is calling **pthml template** with

```
 <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthenticationPopup" name="authentication-popup" as="authentication-popup" template="Magento_Customer::account/authentication-popup.phtml">
```

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/authentication-popup.phtml

This file is calling **js layout** with code:

```
     <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#authenticationPopup": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getJsLayout() ?>
            }
        }
    </script>
```

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/view/authentication-popup.js

this file is called the last **html template** where should be a **static block** from admin panel, with code:

```
    define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    // ......... //
], function ($, ko, /* ... ... ... .... ... */) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        registerUrl: window.authenticationPopup.customerRegisterUrl,
        forgotPasswordUrl: window.authenticationPopup.customerForgotPasswordUrl,
        autocomplete: window.authenticationPopup.autocomplete,
        modalWindow: null,
        isLoading: ko.observable(false),

        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_Customer/authentication-popup'
        },
    });
});
```

this is how i get this block in php

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('reset_password_notice')->toHtml(); ?>
```

> I tried to **paste it to phtml**, **it doesn't work** !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved by myself.
So for the first step, I started looking for a data provider which helps to send data from **pthml** throught **js** to **html** in vendor/module-customer/

There I found the file **vendor/module-customer/Model/Checkout/ConfigProvider.php**. That was exactly what I need.

Following this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142680/how-to-call-static-block-in-knockout-template-file) I create:

1. **app/code/Theme/Customer/etc/frontend/di.xml** with code:

   ```
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="cms_block_config_provider" xsi:type="object">Theme_Name\Customer\Model\Checkout\ConfigProvider</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
   ```
2. The next step was to create a class which is called in **item** tag: **Theme_Name/Customer/Model/Checkout/ConfigProvider.php**
   with code that extends
   **vendor/module-customer/Model/Checkout/ConfigProvider.php**

> Note! They both **implement the same ConfigProviderInterface**. So in new **ConifgProvider.php** we use the **same interface** to extend data-provider correctly

```
<?php
namespace Theme_Name\Customer\Model\Checkout;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface;

class ConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    /** @var LayoutInterface  */
    protected $_layout;

    public function __construct(LayoutInterface $layout)
    {
        $this->_layout = $layout;
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        $cmsBlockId = 'block_ID'; // id of cms block to use

        return [
            'cms_block_message' => $this->_layout->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId($cmsBlockId)->toHtml()
        ];
    }
}
```

Good. The provider is configured.

3)The last one needed to override the frontend **html KO** template:

> **app/design/frontend/theme_name/Magento_Customer/web/template/authentication-popup.html**

Write the next:

```
<div data-bind="html: window.checkoutConfig.cms_block_message"></div>
```